# How can Apple Watch listen to data change on iPhone?

Tags: swift, watchkit, shared-data

Let's say the iPhone has a text field or any internal data, upon the data change, I want to push it automatically to the Apple Watch.   I know I can use the share data.  But that seems to require user to initiate the call (e.g. pressing a button) on the Watch.  Is there a listener on the Apple Watch that I can use if there is a change in the shared data?  Or there is way for the iPhone to automatically push data to the watch, and the watch just receive it and display it?  Or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30615542/1673045) answer. `MMWormhole` seems a good way to communicate between App and its extensions (i.e. Watch App).

Hope this helped.

Comment: Get half working. I can have MMWormhole bridge in the Iphone app., but it is not identified in Watch App..
See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828354/get-unresolved-identifier-for-mmwormhole-in-watch-interfacecontroller-swift